# how to iterate through objects, react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, iteration

I want to make the following code iterate through an object I created.

```
function itemContent(number) {
  return (
    <div >
      <div className="item">
          <div className="itemPic">
            <img src={work.worked[i].picture} alt={work.worked[i].alt} />
          </div>
          <div className="itemInfo">
            <div className="itemInfoLeft">
              <p>{work.worked[i].title}</p>
              <p>{work.worked[i].intro}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="itemInfoRight">
              <p>{work.worked[i].source}</p>
              <p>{work.worked[i].date}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

The following is my object:

```
const worked = {
  redo: {
    picture: `../../images/redo_logo.jpg`,
    alt: `----`,
    title: `/////`,
    source: `RE-DO consulting`,
    intro: `lorem`,
    date: `Aug 2020 -`,
  },
  kth: {
    picture: `../../images/kth_Building.jpg`,
    alt: `-------`,
    title: `hmm`,
    source: `bleh`,
    intro: `lorem.`,
    date: `Aug 2020 -`,
  },
```

As you can see I only want the code to iterate through the first objects (redo and kth). Any idea how to do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As i see the data is object of object. You can access the picture data by writing src={worked.redo.picture}, if it's an url. If you store the image locally, you need to import the image first, assign it as variable, then use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
function itemContent(number) {
  const workedItems = Object.values(work.worked);
  return (
    <div>
    {workedItems.map(item =>
      <div className="item">
          <div className="itemPic">
            <img src={item.picture} alt={item.alt} />
          </div>
          <div className="itemInfo">
            <div className="itemInfoLeft">
              <p>{item.title}</p>
              <p>{item.intro}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="itemInfoRight">
              <p>{item.source}</p>
              <p>{item.date}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      }
      </div>
  )
}
```

`Object.values(work.worked)` returns following array:

```js
[
  {
    "picture": "../../images/redo_logo.jpg",
    "alt": "----",
    "title": "/////",
    "source": "RE-DO consulting",
    "intro": "lorem",
    "date": "Aug 2020 -"
  },
  {
    "picture": "../../images/kth_Building.jpg",
    "alt": "-------",
    "title": "hmm",
    "source": "bleh",
    "intro": "lorem.",
    "date": "Aug 2020 -"
  }
]
```

If you only want to iterate over `redo` and `kth` and ignore other keys of `work.worked` you can use this:

```
const workedItems = [work.worked.redo, work.worked.kth];
```